# Extract from column Date class only in R

Tags: r

I have a bizarre database with all sorts of date types, such as:

```
datfra <- data.frame(ExactDate = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                     DateEstimated = c("1974", "22/12/1984","<1982","year?","23/05/1981" ))

> datfra
  ExactDate DateEstimated
1        NA          1974
2        NA    22/12/1984
3        NA         <1982
4        NA          year?
5        NA    23/05/1981
```

Would I would like to achieve is to transfer correct dates (the ones fitting dd/mm/yyyy) to the column `ExactDate` and leaving the  unfitting ones as `NA`'s such as:

```
> desired_datfra 
   ExactDate DateEstimated
1       NA          1974
2 22/12/1984    22/12/1984
3       NA         <1982
4       NA          year?
5 23/05/1981    23/05/1981
```

Any help will be welcomed!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `as.Date` and `format`, non-matching dates automatically get discarded.

```
transform(datfra, ExactDate=format(as.Date(DateEstimated, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%d/%m/%Y'))
#    ExactDate DateEstimated
# 1       <NA>          1974
# 2 22/12/1984    22/12/1984
# 3       <NA>         <1982
# 4       <NA>         year?
# 5 23/05/1981    23/05/1981
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `dmy` from `lubridate` package.

By using this function only the dates with the correct format will be parsed the other will left NA.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
datfra %>% 
  mutate(ExactDate = dmy(DateEstimated))
```

```
   ExactDate DateEstimated
1       <NA>          1974
2 1984-12-22    22/12/1984
3       <NA>         <1982
4       <NA>         year?
```